# Keras: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable. Unable to call model.fit() or model.fit_generator() on very simple CNN model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am workimg on `MNIST Hand Sign Dataset` for classification. I have my (28*28) images pixels in a numpy array as:

```
X_train.shape, X_val.shape
>>
((2496, 28, 28, 1), (996, 28, 28, 1))
```

I have used `ImageDataGenerator` to make batches and train the model. I have been the following instructions:

```
Batch size =50, epoch=20
All filter (kernel) sizes are 3x3
Initial Conv2D layer with 64 filters
MaxPooling layer following this
Second Conv2D layer with 128 filters
Dense output layer after this
```

My model is as follows:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=1./255.0)
train_gen = datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=50)
val_gen = datagen.flow(X_val,y_val, batch_size=50)

input_ = Input(shape=(28,28,1))
x = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3))(input_)
x = ELU()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3))(x)
x = Conv2D(128,kernel_size=(3,3))(input_)
x = ELU()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(24,activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_,outputs=out)
model.compile(loss=sparse_categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_gen,epochs=20,)
```

I have used `Sparse Categorical Cross Entropy` because I have some missing class values in my y_labels. There are 24 classes from 0-24 but class=9 missing.

Can someone tell me why is that hapenning??

I think the problem is in `train_gen` because `next(train_gen)` gives me the same error.

Lower half of the error is:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py in get_index(uid, i)
    404         The value at index `i`.
    405     """
--> 406     return _SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid][i]
    407 
    408 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     63         index_array = self.index_array[self.batch_size * idx:
     64                                        self.batch_size * (idx + 1)]
---> 65         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
     66 
     67     def __len__(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/numpy_array_iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    152             x = self.image_data_generator.apply_transform(
    153                 x.astype(self.dtype), params)
--> 154             x = self.image_data_generator.standardize(x)
    155             batch_x[i] = x
    156 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py in standardize(self, x)
    702         """
    703         if self.preprocessing_function:
--> 704             x = self.preprocessing_function(x)
    705         if self.rescale:
    706             x *= self.rescale

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: You should include the full traceback, errors without context are meaningless.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this part:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=1./255.0)
```

The `preprocessing_function` parameter expects a function, not a float value. You probably confused it with the `rescale` parameter:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.0)
```

Comment: Oh! my bad. Sorry that I wasted your time. This is exactly what happened.